# Something about tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I just want to define a class using `tkinter`, but in the class, the button can not show on the `root`.This is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


class EasyCalculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry('600x600')
            self.root.title('Calculator')

            
        def Interface(self):    
            Button1 = Button(self.root,text='hi',bg='yellow')
            Button1.pack()
            

        def show(self):
            self.root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Calculator1 = EasyCalculator()
    Calculator1.show()
```

Comment: you aren't calling the Interface function so the button isn't initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `Calculator1.interface()` is never called, so the button can't appear.

Add `Calculator1.interface()` before your `Calculator1.show()`, and it should function:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


class EasyCalculator:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry('600x600')
            self.root.title('Calculator')

            
        def Interface(self):    
            Button1 = Button(self.root,text='hi',bg='yellow')
            Button1.pack()
            

        def show(self):
            self.root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Calculator1 = EasyCalculator()
    Calculator1.Interface()
    Calculator1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just call the interface

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


class EasyCalculator:
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry('600x600')
            self.root.title('Calculator')

            
        def Interface(self):    
            Button1 = Button(self.root,text='hi',bg='yellow')
            Button1.pack()
            

        def show(self):
            self.root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Calculator1 = EasyCalculator()
    Calculator1.Interface()
    Calculator1.show()
```

This is because when you call the `EasyCalculator` class only `__init__(self)` is executed.

Alternatively you can edit the `__init__(self)` as folows:

```
        def __init__(self):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.geometry('600x600')
            self.root.title('Calculator')
            Button1 = Button(self.root,text='hi',bg='yellow')
            Button1.pack()
```